# XSL:if statement is not identifying required items in xml data

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a novice at XSL, so please forgive my ignorance.  I'm trying to construct a table that pulls out only certain elements from a resource pool - those tagged as "TeamMember".  I think I have a problem either with the xsl:if syntax, or with the way I'm referencing the XML data.

The XSL code is -

```
<xsl:for-each select="miradi:Resource/miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/..">
<xsl:if test="miradi:Resource/miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/miradi:code = TeamMember">
<xsl:value-of select="miradi:ResourceSurname"/>
```

the XML data is -

```
<miradi:ResourcePool><miradi:Resource Id="2530">
<miradi:ResourceResourceType>Person</miradi:ResourceResourceType>
<miradi:ResourceIdentifier>DA</miradi:ResourceIdentifier>
<miradi:ResourceSurname>Andrews</miradi:ResourceSurname>
<miradi:ResourcePosition>Manager</miradi:ResourcePosition>
<miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer><miradi:code>TeamMember</miradi:code </miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer>
</miradi:Resource>
```

When I remove the xsl:if statement the code correctly builds a table showing a row for each Resource; but I only want to show a row for each resource that is tagged with "TeamMember".  When I include the XSL:if statement I don't get any rows in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Try `.. = 'TeamMember'` - with quotes, as you are testing a *literal* string.

Comment: Without quotes it is recognized as a child element `<TeamMember>`, which doesn't exist in your XML

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've still got a lot to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

First, after doing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="miradi:Resource/miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/..">
```

you are (probably) in the context of `miradi:Resource`. I say "probably", because you do not show us the starting context. It also makes very little sense to go down to `miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer`, then back up to the parent `miradi:Resource`, but that's another issue.

From this context, the expression you use in your `xsl:if` test:

```
miradi:Resource/miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/miradi:code
```

selects nothing, because `miradi:Resource` is not a child of the context node.

The other issue is that your condition tests against a non-existing node, instead of a literal string. Your test should actually be:

```
<xsl:if test="miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/miradi:code = 'TeamMember'">
```

Or you could simply do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="miradi:Resource[miradi:ResourceRoleCodesContainer/miradi:code = 'TeamMember']">
    <xsl:value-of select="miradi:ResourceSurname"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Michael - this has fixed my problem.  It all seems so easy once you can see how it's done!

Comment: Good. For your next question, please make sure to provide a **reproducible** example. This means, among [other things](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a **well-formed** XML input and a **complete**, if minimized, XSLT stylesheet.